# Commutation relations of symmetry generators in SUSY

Tags: supersymmetry, anticommutator, superalgebra

It is well known that the generators
$$ Q_\alpha = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha} - i \sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot \beta} \bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta} \partial_\mu $$
and 
$$ \bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{\theta}^\dot{\alpha}} + i \theta^\beta\sigma^\mu_{\beta \dot \alpha}  \partial_\mu $$

where $\theta^\alpha$, $\bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta}$ are Grassmann variables, obey the anti-commutation relations

$$ \{Q_\alpha, \bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}\} = 2i \sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot \alpha} \partial_\mu $$
$$ \{Q_\alpha, Q_\beta\} = \{\bar{Q}_\dot{\alpha}, \bar{Q}_\dot{\beta}\} = 0 $$

**Question**: I want to explicitly verify those anti-commutation relations, say for example $\{Q_\alpha, Q_\beta\} = 0$.

However, I'm unable to reproduce that result.
I might get as far as follows:

$$ \{Q_\alpha, Q_\beta\} = 
\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}\} - i \sigma^\mu_{\beta \dot \beta} \bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta} \{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\alpha}, \partial_\mu\} - i \sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot \beta} \bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta} \{ \partial_\mu, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\beta} \} - \sigma^\mu_{\alpha \dot \beta} \sigma^\nu_{\beta \dot \gamma} \{ \bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta} \partial_\mu, \bar{\theta}^\dot{\gamma} \partial_\nu \}
$$

where the last term vanishes due to the anti-commutation of the $\bar{\theta}$.

Any help on how to proceed with the calculation towards the desired result is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you get anticommutators in the 2 cross-terms?

Comment: I think the two terms in the middle should not be there if you use Leibniz rule for Grassmann variables

Comment: @Qmechanic I simply pulled out the $\sigma^\mu_{\beta \dot \beta} \bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta}$ factor out of the cross term of the commutator, am I not allowed to do that?

Comment: Only if you account for sign factors when supercommuting objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. $Q_{\alpha}$ and $Q_{\beta}$ supercommute because they only consist of objects that manifestly supercommute with each other.
2. In contrast,  $Q_{\alpha}$ and $\overline{Q}_{\dot{\alpha}}$ only fail to supercommute because the Grassmann-variables and their corresponding derivatives don't supercommute
   $$ \{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^{\alpha}},~  \theta^{\beta}\}_+ ~=~\delta_{\alpha}^{\beta},\qquad \{\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\theta}^{\dot{\alpha}}},~  \overline{\theta}^{\dot{\beta}}\}_+ ~=~\delta_{\dot{\alpha}}^{\dot{\beta}}. $$